# How can I automatically bring the text in the box to the center with bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, padding, bootstrap-cards

I need boxes that text in the center. I tried px classes but it doesn't work. it's near but not exactly center. which bootstrap class  can ı use in this subject ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ggxM.png)

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the applicable html text that you have created.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest way to center things in bootstrap is to use [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/):

```
<div class="d-flex align-content-center align-items-center">
  <span>Your Text</span>
</div>
```